# Why my 2 computers cannot ping one another?:

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping

I have 2 computers connected to the same router.

Ip config of one says

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : www.tendawifi.com
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3804:2d04:a591:7142%6
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.108
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1


Ipconfig of another is similar except that it's 192.168.0.106

C:\Users\vbcbu>ping 192.168.0.106

Pinging 192.168.0.106 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.106:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Users\vbcbu>

They're connected to the same router.
```

Why can't they ping each other?

I can however, ping my android phone

```
C:\Users\vbcbu>ping 192.168.0.103

Pinging 192.168.0.103 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.103: bytes=32 time=212ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.103: bytes=32 time=100ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.103: bytes=32 time=61ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.103: bytes=32 time=134ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.103:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 61ms, Maximum = 212ms, Average = 126ms
```

This is tracert result

```
Tracing route to DESKTOP-MNQO6R4 [192.168.0.106]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

I can ping gateway

```
C:\Users\vbcbu>ping 192.168.0.1

Pinging 192.168.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 4ms, Maximum = 12ms, Average = 6ms

C:\Users\vbcbu>
```

I can do this from both computers

Comment: Are you sure that the second computer has an IP of `192.168.0.106`? Also, from both devices can you ping you default gateway?

Comment: I can ping default gateway from both device

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Possible reasons:

- One or both computers not physically connected to network (can you ping anything else on the network, such as the router?)
- One or both computers have 2 connections to the same network and one computer is expecting a reply on the wrong NIC.  This can happen if one or both computers have a wired and Wi-Fi connection to the same network.
- Firewall or security software on one or both computers is blocking ping.
- Default gateway or subnet mask not the same on one or both computers.
- Managed switch inbetween both computers has port disabled, MAC address blocked, 802.11 authentication failed, or other feature that's interfering.  If your switch or router doesn't have a "CONSOLE" port this probably doesn't apply.
- If both computers are on a public Wifi network you may need to check for a captive portal page in the browser and accept any terms and conditions or sign in.
- One or both computers may be connected to a corporate-type VPN (Cisco Anyconnect, Global Protect) that is overriding all local routing.
- Some sort of NIC offload engine is enabled and is not working properly.  Update NIC drivers or go into NIC driver options and disable all options with "Offload" in the name.
- Corrupt OS installation or faulty cabling, NIC hardware in PC, or switch.

Comment: both are connected through the internet through the router. so not an issue. What the hell is NIC? What exactly I should do to check

Comment: This question should have been closed instead of answered, its a dupe of the same question asked by the author